# Solved : Firebase says firebaseui didn't support v9 But firebaseui say it supports v9 . Which one correct?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

**Solution**

```
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={firebaseAuthConfig}firebaseAuth={getAuth()} className="googleBtn"/>
```

[view more](https://github.com/thanhtutzaw/too/blob/main/Components/FirebaseAuth.js)

**Problem**

Firebase not initalized but I do in _app.js [See Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brt5Q.png)

I initalized manually again it says **duplicate** [See Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgA1Y.png)

I authenticate with Next-firebase-auth package.
I download the example files and it works ( Firebase v8 & firebaseui v6 )

So I install auth package in my app and changed some files. [here how I Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzeyR.png)

- Firebase v9
- firebaseui v6

And I copy / paste some code and run the code but It didn't work .
Error told me to intialize firebase app (I think I don't need because already initlize in _app.js)

And then I initialize firebase app again and Error say Firebase app already initalize (duplicate)

> firebaseerror: firebase: no firebase app '[default]' has been created - call firebase app.initializeapp() (app-compat/no-app).

```
<StyledFirebaseAuth
            uiConfig={firebaseAuthConfig}
Error line-> firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution** I make a mistake with version problem

```
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={firebaseAuthConfig}firebaseAuth={getAuth()} className="googleBtn"/>
```

[view more](https://github.com/thanhtutzaw/too/blob/main/Components/FirebaseAuth.js)